# wp admin page white screen except nav

Tags: wordpress

Please i am trying to fix a wordpress problem i am having. I sign into my backend (wp-admin) and i can see the nav portion but it shows white when i click on any navigation panel botton. I saw an anser in one of the posts that said i should go to wp-admin\includes\screen.php and change "_help_sidebar; ?>" to "_help_sidebar; ?>". However, this line of code is not present in my screen.php file.

kindly advise.

NB: I am having similar problems in all my add on domains on a shared server.

thank you.

[image: Here is an image description of the problem]

Comment: Have you made any recent changes in the code? Added any plugin?

Comment: If you have access to error logs they should provide you with the information on why this is happening. It is likely that you have a coding error  somewhere. You should also create a new administrator user and delete the default 'admin' user account to tighten up on security.